# App is not open when local notification click in windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I developed a windows phone app. in this scheduled local notification.
**what happen is notification came but whenever I click notification app was not open it goes to back.**

below is my code:

```
string textLine1 = "Sample Toast App";
            string textLine2 = "This is a sample message.";
            string contentString =
              "<toast duration=\"long\">\n" +
                "<visual>\n" +
                  "<binding template=\"ToastText02\">\n" +
                    "<text id=\"1\">" + textLine1 + "</text>\n" +
                    "<text id=\"2\">" + textLine2 + "</text>\n" +
                  "</binding>\n" +
                "</visual>\n" +
              "</toast>\n";



XmlDocument content = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
content.LoadXml(contentString);

DateTime EventDate = new DateTime(2016, 02, 11, 12, 45, 00);

ToastNotifier toastNotifier =ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
var scheduledToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(content, EventDate);
toastNotifier.AddToSchedule(scheduledToast);
```

in the above code

> I am replace `EventDate` to `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)` then app was
>   open.

```
ToastNotifier toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
var scheduledToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(content, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));
toastNotifier.AddToSchedule(scheduledToast);
```

what  should I do. please help me.

Comment: Check your payload string, all backword slashes and double quaote!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set '`launch`' attribute as your app landing page. Sample below.

```
<toast launch="/Views/HomeView.xaml?toast=test">
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastText01">
            <text id="1">Hello World!</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

Comment: actually I am not putting any icon in my development project.so not showing.please see my above code. in that code whenever i put DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30).then its working fine, app is open. but DateTime EventDate = new DateTime(2016, 02, 11, 12, 45, 00);I am schudeled like this app was not open.

Comment: both are same.but declaration is different.

Comment: Compare both date time values. May be you have to specify DateTimeKind